# Möbius transformation and stereographic projection

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we know the position of three points in the plane. You can define a stereographic projection from a Möbius transformation , is this possible ?

Comment: Hint: A Mobius transformation preserves direction and orientation.

Comment: Your question is unclear. A Moebius transformation is a biholomorphic map $T:\>\bar{\mathbb C}\to\bar{\mathbb C}$, whereas stereographic projection is a certain standard map $\sigma:\>\bar{\mathbb C}\to S^2$, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the spatial imagination should precede math.

You need to take essentially an *arbitrary* fixed point above your three points to represent North Pole. From the arbitrary point drop perpendicular to the given plane with three points. The foot of perpendicular is the South Pole of tangency.

In a stereographic projection a small circle  containing three points on the sphere gets projected onto a plane tangent to South Pole as a mapped circle made by straight focusing rays originating at the North pole as projection source (shown in a very instructive Youtube demo)... and, *vice-versa*.

I.e. your three points in tangent plane can be mapped back to three points on the sphere on a small circle by *inversions*.

The three connecting lines simply pierce the sphere in the required three points.

You can map circles to circles either way, it is a standard procedure using complex geometry using inversion, I am not repeating the complex transformation.
[MoebiusTransfmn3D](https://video.search.yahoo.com/video/play;_ylt=A0SO8wOtBYNV.TgA7glXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEybGllb24wBGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDQjAzNjJfMQRzZWMDc2M-?p=moebius%20transformations%20revealed&back=https%3A%2F%2Fsearch.yahoo.com%2Fsearch%3Fp%3Dmoebius%2Btransformations%2Brevealed%26type%3DC111US91021D20150206%26ei%3DUTF-8&fr=%26fr%3Dmcafee&turl=http%3A%2F%2Fts2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DWN.vMFewq46fj2QMrx5p2cc4Q%26pid%3D15.1&rurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D0z1fIsUNhO4&tit=M%C3%B6bius%20Transformations%20Revealed%20[HD]&l=2%3A45&vid=fc11ec3cb7c5d0829593ed3e8a18d92d&sigr=11ba9pltb&sigb=135d2o6jt&sigt=115rb6h0h&sigi=11vq13prn)

Answer (score 0):

We note that the Möbius transformations are defined as follows:

$$f_{M}:z\mapsto w=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

We want to map three points: $(z_{1},z_{2},z_{3}) \to (0,1,\infty)$. Starting with the first point, we have:

$$0=f_{M}(z_{1})=\frac{az_{1}+b}{cz_{1}+d} \implies az_{1}+b=0 \implies \frac{-b}{a}=z_{1}$$

We have the second point:

$$1=f_{M}(z_{2})=\frac{az_{2}+b}{cz_{2}+d} \implies az_{2}+b=cz_{2}+d \implies z_{2}=\frac{d-b}{a-c}$$

And finally:

$$\infty=f_{M}(z_{3})=\frac{az_{3}+b}{cz_{3}+d} \implies cz_{3}+d=0 \implies z_{3}=-\frac{d}{c}$$

So we note that there are a family of Möbius transforms who form a stereographic projection given 3 points.